# WebRTC remote users cannot connect to each other

Tags: reactjs, connection, webrtc, local-network

Hello I am trying to connect 3 users in my local network. The host of the whole application can connect to each user. When the host distributes the iceCandidates, then the connection is done and the remote users can talk to the host.

However, the remote users cannot talk to each other. If they distribute their iceCandidates, then no connection is established, although the remote description was set successfully and remote media stream was received. There is no error output either

Even if the remote user sends his candidates to the host, no connection is established. Only the host can cause a connection.

I don't use a stun server, because everything is done in the local network.

I hope someone can give me some advice